# RDD is not working when try to persist into database in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I want to persist my rdd into the mysql database table. I have used a map function to iterate through the RDD and passed each tuple into my function where I make the persistence. Here I want to paralalize my job into master and slave nodes.

But it doesn't working fine and it doesn't call to the function I make the database persistance.

If I use collect() such as  `courseSet.collect().map(m => sendCourseInfo(m))` instead of `courseSet.map(m => sendCourseInfo(m))` this will work fine.

I don't want to use collect() here.

I have searched this in many articles and was unable to figure it out. Can anybody please help me to resolve this.

Below is my code,

```
 .....
  x.toString().split(",")(1),
  x.toString().split(",")(2),
  x.toString().split(",")(3)))

 courseSet.map(m => sendCourseInfo(m))
}

def sendCourseInfo(courseData: (Int, String, String, String)): Unit = {
    try {
      DatabaseUtil.setJDBCConfiguration()

      val jdbcConnection: java.sql.Connection = DatabaseUtil.getConnection

      val statement = "{call insert_course (?,?,?,?)}"
      val callableStatement = jdbcConnection.prepareCall(statement)
      callableStatement.setInt(1, courseData._1)
      callableStatement.setString(2, courseData._2)
      callableStatement.setString(3, courseData._3)
      callableStatement.setString(4, courseData._4)

      callableStatement.executeUpdate
    } catch {
      case e: SQLException => println(e.getStackTrace)
    }
}
```

Comment: try `courseSet.map(m => sendCourseInfo(m)).count`, otherwise the map-statement is never executed (RDD transformations are lazy) or alternatively `courseSet.foreach(m => sendCourseInfo(m))` which is not lazy

Answer (score 0):

You're calling map() on a RDD which is a transformation and not an action. So, for it to execute you need to call some action like,

```
courseSet.foreach(sendCourseInfo)
```

Extra suggestions for what you're doing,

Whatever `x` is, you're casting it to String, splitting it and extracting something from this split. You're doing this thrice for each element in your RDD/Collection. So, you can optimize it with something like this,

```
x.map(_.toString.split(",")).map(x=>(x(1),x(2),x(3)))
```

Next you have to persist this data in DB, MySql in this case. You're using java's usual jdbc connectivity for that, creating a new connection and operation for each element. Instead, with Spark 2.x do something like this,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.Properties

...

case class TableSchema(col1:Int,col2:String,col3:String,col4:String)
val props = new Properties()

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val ss = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

import ss.implicits._

...

props.setProperty("username", "username")
props.setProperty("password", "password")    

val df = rdd.map(_.toString.split(",")).map(x=>TableSchema(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3))).toDF()

df.write.jdbc(s"jdbc:mysql://${mysqlHost}/${mysqlDBName}", "tablename", props)

}
```

Let me know if this helps, Cheers.